# "Faking" a sub-table of results from 3 tables, in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, nested-lists

If I have a table of cases:

```
CASE_NUMBER | CASE_ID | STATUS          | SUBJECT              | 
----------------------------------------------------------------
3108        | 123456  | Closed_Billable | Something Interesting
3109        | 325124  | Closed_Billable | Broken printer
3110        | 432432  | Open_Assigned   | Email not working
```

And a table of calls:

```
PARENT_ID | STATUS    | DUR(H) | DUR(M) | SUBJECT
---------------------------------------------------------------
123456    | Held      | 1      | 30     | Initial discussion
123456    | Cancelled | 0      | 0      | Walk user through
123456    | Held      | 0      | 45     | Remote debug session
325124    | Held      | 1      | 0      | Consultation
325124    | Held      | 1      | 15     | Needs assessment
432432    | Held      | 1      | 30     | Support call
```

And a table of meetings:

```
PARENT_ID | STATUS    | DUR(H) | DUR(M) | SUBJECT
-------------------------------------------------------
123456    | Held      | 3      | 15     | On-site work
325124    | Held      | 2      | 0      | Un-jam printer
432432    | Held      | 1      | 0      | Reconnect network
```

How do I do a select with these parameters (this is not working code, obviously):

```
SELECT cases.case_number, cases.subject, calls.subject, meetings.subject
WHERE  cases.status="Closed_Billable" AND (calls.status="Held" OR meetings.status="Held)
LEFT JOIN cases
ON cases.case_id = calls.parent_id
LEFT JOIN cases
ON cases.case_id = meetings.parent_id
```

and end up with a "faked" nested table like:

```
CASE_NUMBER | CASE SUBJECT          | # CALLS | # MEETINGS | CALL SUBJECT         | MEETING SUBJECT | DURATION (H) | DURATION (M) | TOTAL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3108        | Something Interesting | 2       | 1          |                      |                 |              |              | 5.5H
            |                       |         |            | Initial Discussion   |                 | 1            | 30           |
            |                       |         |            | Remote Debug Session |                 | 0            | 45           |
            |                       |         |            |                      | On-site work    | 3            | 15           |
3109        | Broken printer        | 2       | 1          |                      |                 |              |              | 4.25H
            |                       |         |            | Consultation         |                 | 1            | 0            | 
            |                       |         |            | Needs assessment     |                 | 1            | 15           |
            |                       |         |            |                      | Un-jam printer  | 2            | 0            |
```

I've tried joins and subqueries the best I can figure out, but I get repeated entries - for example, each Meeting in a Case will show say 3 times, once for each Call in that case.

I'm stumped! Obviously there's other fields I'm pulling here, and doing COUNTs of Calls and Meetings, and SUMs of their durations, but I'd be happy just to show a table/sub-table like this.

Is it even possible?

Thanks,
David.

Comment: Have you tried using the **DISTINCT** keyword to get rid of duplicates ?

Comment: first thing, move your where to AFTER the joins and add a FROM clause...  so select <field list> from <table> <joins> where <clauses>

Comment: Coloco - Interestingly enough, DISTINCT doesn't remove the dupes... they're still a "mesh" of repeated set of calls for each meeting

Comment: I would say formatting like that isn't a job for sql, and should probably end up in the application layer. Then again, challenge accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assembling a query result in the exact format you want is .. somewhat of a pain. It can be done, but presentation stuff like that is best left to the application.

That said, this will do what you want:

```
select case when case_id > floor(case_id) then ''
            else case_number
       end case_number,
       coalesce(q1.c, '') calls,
       coalesce(q2.c, '') meetings,
       coalesce(calls.subject, '') `call subject`,
       coalesce(meetings.subject, '') `meeting subject`,
       case when calls.subject is not null then calls.dhour
            when meetings.subject is not null then meetings.dhour
            else ''
       end dhour,
       case when calls.subject is not null then calls.dmin
            when meetings.subject is not null then meetings.dmin
            else ''
       end dhour,
       coalesce(q3.total, '') total
from
(
 select case_number, case_id
   from cases where status = 'Closed_Billable'
 union select case_number, concat(case_id, '.1')
   from cases where status = 'Closed_Billable'
 union select case_number, concat(case_id, '.2')
   from cases where status = 'Closed_Billable'
) main
left join
(select parent_id, count(*) c
         from calls
         where status != 'Cancelled'
         group by parent_id ) q1
  on q1.parent_id = case_id
 left join
      (select parent_id, count(*) c
         from meetings
         group by parent_id) q2
      on q2.parent_id = case_id
    left join
      (select parent_id, sum(dhour + m) total
         from
           (select parent_id, dhour, dmin / 60 m
              from calls
              where status != 'Cancelled'
            union all
            select parent_id, dhour, dmin / 60 m
              from meetings
           ) qq
         group by parent_id
       ) q3
      on q3.parent_id = case_id
left join calls
  on concat(calls.parent_id, '.1') = main.case_id
left join meetings
  on concat(meetings.parent_id, '.2') = main.case_id
order by case_id asc
```

Note, i've renamed your duration fields because i dislike the parenthesis in them.

We have to mangle the case_id a little bit inside the query in order to be able to get you your blank rows / fields - those are what makes the query cumbersome

There's a demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d59d4/21

**edited code to work with different schema in comment fiddle**

```
select case when case_id > floor(case_id) then ''
            else case_number
       end case_number,
       coalesce(q1.c, '') calls,
       coalesce(q2.c, '') meetings,
       coalesce(calls.name, '') `call subject`,
       coalesce(meetings.name, '') `meeting subject`,
       case when calls.name is not null then calls.duration_hours
            when meetings.name is not null then meetings.duration_hours
            else ''
       end duration_hours,
       case when calls.name is not null then calls.duration_minutes
            when meetings.name is not null then meetings.duration_minutes
            else ''
       end duration_hours,
       coalesce(q3.total, '') total
from
(
 select case_number, id as case_id
   from cases where status = 'Closed_Billable'
 union select case_number, concat(id, '.1') as case_id
   from cases where status = 'Closed_Billable'
 union select case_number, concat(id, '.2') as case_id
   from cases where status = 'Closed_Billable'
) main
left join
(select parent_id, count(*) c
         from calls
         where status != 'Cancelled'
         group by parent_id ) q1
  on q1.parent_id = case_id
 left join
      (select parent_id, count(*) c
         from meetings
         group by parent_id) q2
      on q2.parent_id = case_id
    left join
      (select parent_id, sum(duration_hours + m) total
         from
           (select parent_id, duration_hours, duration_minutes / 60 m
              from calls
              where status != 'Cancelled'
            union all
            select parent_id, duration_hours, duration_minutes / 60 m
              from meetings
           ) qq
         group by parent_id
       ) q3
      on q3.parent_id = case_id
left join calls
  on concat(calls.parent_id, '.1') = main.case_id
left join meetings
  on concat(meetings.parent_id, '.2') = main.case_id
order by case_id asc
```

Comment: Flabbergasted. Thank you. Two minor points - when I translate this into my PHPMyAdmin on the live db, I get 'column id is ambiguous', and your excellent demo is forgetting to filter on the cases where status="Closed_Billable" ... both of which I can't figure out. But wow...!

Comment: sorry, i'll add that missing status in - where does the `id` column come into it? i didnt see it in your sample tables

Comment: @DavidSzego `closed_billable` status filter added in.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. In each table, an entry has ID (which is globally unique), and calls.parent_id /meetings.parent_id relates to cases.id

Comment: Anyways, if you can help tweak that, amazing. Regardless, the sheer effort and detail in this answer deserves accepting! And a beer! Many thanks! Msg me if you're for hire for SugarCRM custom reporting. Might well use your skills.

Comment: @DavidSzego if you could update the sqlfiddle link i posted with your actual schema / data and the query how you've modified it, i'll fix it up for you

Comment: Thanks again. Not enough rep to chat, so pardon the comment thread. I copied it to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bb97 as I couldn't figure how to edit yours. I do indeed feel dumb in this thread!

Comment: @DavidSzego fiddle is being a pain - answer updated with query appropriate to your fiddle (as a second query, left the original intact as it matches the question)

Answer (score -1):

You can't really get final results like that without some seriously ugly "wrapper" queries, of this sort:

```
SET @prevCaseNum := 'blahdyblahnowaythisshouldmatchanything';
SET @prevCaseSub := 'seeabovetonotmatchanything';
SELECT IF(@prevCaseNum = CASE_NUMBER, '', CASE_NUMBER) AS CASE_NUMBER
    , IF(@prevCaseNum = CASE_NUMBER AND @prevCaseSubject = CASE_SUBJECT, '', CASE_SUBJECT) AS CASE_SUBJECT
    , etc.....
    , @prevCaseNum := CASE_NUMBER AS prevCaseNum
    , @prevCaseSubject = CASE_SUBJECT AS prevCaseSub
    , etc....
FROM ( [the real query] ORDER BY CASE_NUMBER, etc....) AS trq
;
```

And then wrap all that with another select to strip the prevCase fields.
And even this still won't give you the blanks you want on the "upper right".

Comment: you can't reliably use variables like that. there's no guarantee that the equality checks happen before the assignments, or vice versa.

Comment: @pala_, It's worked every time I've had need of it. It may or may not be official, but results fields are evaluated left to right in my experience with MySQL. I am not sure about other RDBMS providers though.

Comment: [it is not guaranteed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) - specifically this quote "However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined."